# URL Rewrite ONLY html pages

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting

OK ..I've used the common URL rewrite to redirect http to https.

Problem I'm seeing:  Google crawls for sitemaps.xml and ads.txt and isn't happy.

Can someone help me with the http to https redirect for HMTL pages only so the .xml and .txt are ignored?

URL rewrite is Definitely my weakness.

IIS 7

Comment: Could you show some code? Or, at least, some of what you've already tried? Stack Overflow isn't a general code-writing service.

Comment: Thanks.  Here's my working rewrite:
          <rule name="https" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="www.123.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.123.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>